# Make a TextArea with much Text and its Frame respond faster

Tags: java, swing, awt

How do I make a TextArea with about **2MB** Data respond faster?
lineWrap is enabled (**`true`**)
The Frame is responding very slow when I enable doubleBufferd

**The Data (all char in UTF-8) which should be displayed is stored in a String**

Resizing the Window takes about 3 seconds
It's similar to this:

```
String result = "";
int i = 0;
    while (i < 1000000) {
    result += i;
    i++;
}
textArea.setText(result);
```

Comment: What TextArea are you using exactly?

Comment: JTextArea with Scrollbars

Comment: use can use a BufferedReader, with a wrapper FileReader. Would the InputStream be more efficient

Comment: I read in the Data already with a DataInputStream (byte[]) but now I want to display it

Comment: Use the read(...) method of the text area to read the data.

Answer (score 1):

How does your 200 KiB text look like?

You didn't provide a [minimal working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so I have created one for you.

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public final class Main extends JFrame {

    private final JTextArea text;

    Main() {
        super("Just a Test");
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.text = new JTextArea();
        this.text.setLineWrap(true);
        this.text.setDoubleBuffered(true);
        this.add(new JScrollPane(this.text));
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 600));
        this.pack();
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    void appendFile(final File file) throws IOException {
        try (final BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {
            while (true) {
                final String line = br.readLine();
                if (line == null) {
                    break;
                }
                this.text.append(line + '\n');
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final Main self = new Main();
        for (final String arg : args) {
            try {
                self.appendFile(new File(arg));
            } catch (final IOException e) {
                System.err.printf("error: Cannot load text from file '%s': %s\n",
                                  arg, e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }

}
```

The problem seems to be that the word wrapping algorithm used internally becomes inefficient for extremely long lines.

- If I load an ordinary text file of that size with line lengths of about 100 characters, resizing the window happens almost instantaneously even if I resize the window to such small a size that every line has to be wrapped multiple times.
- However, when I load a text file of the same size that has all text on a single line, resizing takes significantly longer.
- Finally, when I have all text on a single line and that line **does not end with a `\n`**, resizing becomes extremely slow. (Although still not the three seconds you've reported, but then again, I tried this on a pretty fast computer.) This almost looks like a bug in the *Swing* code because absence of a terminating `\n` should not make the algorithm that much slower.

So my first suggestion would be that you revisit your text source. A file with 200 KiB text on a single line seems pretty strange and if your GUI becomes somewhat slow for that, it wouldn't be too bad in my opinion. (As long as the program still functions correctly.) If the text is generated by your own program, by all means, insert line breaks where they make sense. Humans can read text more easily if it has line breaks at appropriate places. Many other applications will have troubles processing such long lines too so everybody wins.

If you think you're hit by the trailing `\n` issue, try appending an additional `\n` to the text in your `JTextArea` at the end of the text.

As a last resort, you could consider disabling line wrap and instead add horizontal scroll bars. But I noticed that the `JTextArea` isn't very happy about extremely long lines in this case either.

Comment: There is no need for `setDoubleBuffered(true)`. Swing is double buffered by default.

Comment: @camickr I think you are right and I don't do this in my own code but OP says they did it so I wanted to see whether it has an effect. It turned out that the resizing isn't slower / faster when I don't set it.

Comment: I can't open the file (.docx, .jpg) line by line because I would loose data

Comment: @MaxiKopp Sorry, I am confused. Are you displaying a JPEG to your users with a `TextArea`?

Comment: I'm not sure what this means but you can still append a `\n` at the end of whatever you set the text to. I also realized that your text size just grew by a factor of 10. ;-) I would really recommend you craft an MCVE.